# MySQL - Many to Many - Weighting/Order the relation table rows - Rebuilding order when relations are unlinked

Tags: php, mysql

I need advice on the best way to accomplish the following design schema.

I have a two tables with many-to-many relationship. And one table that links them all together.

```
tableName: playlist
  columns: 
     id
     name
track
  columns: 
     id
     name
playlist_track
   playlist_id { onDelete: CASCADE }
   track_id { onDelete: CASCADE }
   order_no
```

Sample data for the relation mapper table:

```
Entry1:
   playlist_id: 1
   track_id: 1
   order_no: 1
Entry2:
   playlist_id: 1
   track_id: 2
   order_no: 2
Entry3:
   playlist_id: 1
   track_id: 3
   order_no: 3
Entry4:
   playlist_id: 1
   track_id: 4
   order_no: 4
```

When Entry3 is deleted, the item order for playlist_id: 1 would be [1,2,4], which would result in unprettiness.

What would be the best way to "rebuild" the order when an item is removed?

The alternatives in mind would be between the two:

1. PHP code that fetches all tracks in a playlist and rebuilds them to [1,2,3]
2. MySQL trigger of some sort that does this task automagically(?)

Anyone with some concrete advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE playlist_track
SET order_no = order_no -1
WHERE playlist_id = $whatever_id_you_deleted
AND order_no > $whatever_order_no_was_deleted
```

On the other hand, you can think of the `order_no` as some kind of weight (heavier items sink to the bottom). Then an update of the `order_no` is not necessary. Depends on your other queries if this is appropriate. If you frequently have queries like "give me the next item in the playlist" or "give me item `n` in the playlist", then an update might be worth it. But if you usually fetch a complete playlist, I wouldn't bother updating.

If you do update the order, you will need some kind of automation (like triggers), because items can be deleted from the playlist by deleting the track that they reference.

Comment: I guess triggers would be the easiest way to go, since the order will be updated quite often. If a track is deleted, it will cascade onto the playlist_track table also. Would be handy to skip the additionaly queries using a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE playlist_track SET order_no = order_no - 1 WHERE playlist_id = 3 AND order_no > 3
```